# LINQ to XML select multiple elements?

Tags: linq-to-xml

How do I select multiple elements (with different names) in a [LINQ to XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_XML) query?

I have a query like this:

```
var elems = from descendant in doc.Descendants("foo")
                            select descendant;
```

But I want to select both foo and bar, sort of like this:

```
var elems = from descendant in doc.Descendants("foo" || "bar")
                            select descendant;
```

But that is just to illustrate what I want to do, I know this is not correct syntax. I don't know how it should be done with LINQ to XML, so what is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only pass in one `XName` into those methods.  Just leave them out there and do normal LINQ filtering.

```cs
var elems = doc.Descendants()
               .Where(desc => desc.Name == "foo" || desc.Name == "bar");
```

Using an XPath is another way.

```cs
var elems = doc.XPathSelectElements("//foo|//bar");
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, one option:

```
var elems = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == (XName) "foo" ||
                                         x.Name == (XName) "bar");
```

Comment: @Anders: I don't think he did, actually... my answer ID (4803662) is lower than his (4803747). But hey, it doesn't matter :) (See also http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4803598/timeline)

Comment: Ok, sorry, from the time SO showed it looked the other way around, but thanks again to both anyway!